# Throwing a pencil up in an elevator speeding upward

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-fall

The classic question is "What happens to a pencil if I, standing in an elevator speeding downward,  lets go of it at the exact second the elevator begins its fall?" As I understand, the pencil seems to hover in the air as it falls at the exact same rate I do. But, what happens to a pencil if I, standing in an elevator speeding upward, lets go of it at the exact second the elevator begins to rise? Will there be more of an upward force on it? My thinking is that I appear to weigh more if I would standing on a scale, so would the pencil move upward, if the acceleration was constant?

Comment: it is the same as being in a planet with larger gravity $g'$, where $g'=9.8m/s^2+a$

Comment: Do you know what a fictitious force is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like yourself, the pencil also appears to weigh more, as reckoned by you who is at rest in the frame of reference of the elevator.  So the pencil falls faster.  It is as if gravity had increased.

Answer (score 1):

For the situation where the elevator starts going up immediately when you drop the pen, we can do a transformation on the equation of motion of the pen to find the answer to this.

Say $x$ is positive in the up direction. To a stationary observer outside the elevator,

$$x_{\text{pen}}(t)= x_0 -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 $$

where $x_0$ is the initial height of the pen. The floor of the elevator is moving like
$$x_{\text{elevator floor}}(t)= +\frac{1}{2}at^2 $$

where I assumed the initial velocity of the elevator to be $0$, it just closed and started going up with constant acceleration $a$. I also set the origin $x=0$ on the floor of the building, which matches the elevator floor at $t=0$.

Inside the elevator (let us call this the prime frame):
$$x'_{\text{elevator floor}}(t)= 0$$
and we want $x'_{\text{pen}}(t)$. Via vector addition,
$$x'_{\text{pen}}+x_{\text{elevator floor}} =x_{\text{pen}}$$
so rearranging,
$$x'_{\text{pen}} =x_{\text{pen}}-x_{\text{elevator floor}}$$
and so
$$x'_{\text{pen}}(t) =x_0-\frac{1}{2}gt^2-\frac{1}{2}at^2 =x_0-\frac{1}{2}(g+a)t^2 $$
so if we were to use Newton's second Law in the elevator frame, we would find that the force consistent with this pen's acceleration is $-(g+a)m$.

Throughout this solution both $g>0$ and $a>0$ by the definition I've adopted.